# Error adding Data to my SQLite Database on Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite

New to Android Studio and SQLite so some help would be appreciated.

Creating an app where someone enters in their friend details and it adds them to a Database.

I've created my Database Class and my Activity to add friends but whenever I attempt to add them to the database, I get an error in the logcat stating:

```
11-16 20:40:20.083 2641-2641/com.example.kod45.myapplication E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting EMAIL=pm@gmail.com NAME=paul ID=1 SURNAME=pail
                                                                           android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table friends_table has no column named EMAIL (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO friends_table(EMAIL,NAME,ID,SURNAME) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
                                                                           #################################################################
                                                                           Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
                                                                           Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                                                                            (table friends_table has no column named EMAIL (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO friends_table(EMAIL,NAME,ID,SURNAME) VALUES (?,?,?,?))
```

Here is my Database Handler:

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Friends.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "friends_table";
    public static final String ID_COL = "ID";
    public static final String EMAIL = "EMAIL";
    public static final String FIRST_NAME = "NAME";
    public static final String SURNAME = "SURNAME";

public DBHandler(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    String CREATE_FRIENDS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + ID_COL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + EMAIL + "TEXT,"
            + FIRST_NAME + "TEXT,"
            + SURNAME + "TEXT" + ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_FRIENDS_TABLE);
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion) {
    // example of drop old tables and Re-
    //create tables.
    //you can alter tables such as add
    //columns, etc. but not drop tables
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists "
            + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addNewFriend(Friend newFriend)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(ID_COL, newFriend.getFriendID());
    values.put(EMAIL, newFriend.getEmailAddress());
    values.put(FIRST_NAME, newFriend.getFirstName());
    values.put(SURNAME, newFriend.getSurname());

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public ArrayList<Friend> getAllFriends()
{
    ArrayList<Friend> friendList = new ArrayList<Friend>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do
            {
                Friend friend = new Friend();
                friend.setFriendID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                friend.setEmailAddress(cursor.getString(1));
                friend.setFirstName(cursor.getString(2));
                friend.setSurname(cursor.getString(3));


                //Adding to list
                friendList.add(friend);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) ;


        }
    return friendList;
    }
```

}

And also how I am adding:

```
    public class AddFriends extends AppCompatActivity {
        DBHandler myDB;
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_friends);
        myDB = new DBHandler(this);
    }

    public void addFriend(View v) {
        EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailText);
        EditText firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstnameText);
        EditText surname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.surnameText);
        EditText id = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.idText);
        Button addData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addFriendButton);

        //Passing them as strings
        String emailString = email.getText().toString();
        String firstNameString = firstName.getText().toString();
        String surnameString = surname.getText().toString();
        int idNum = Integer.parseInt(id.getText().toString());

        String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9]+\\.+[a-z0-9]+";

        if(emailString.matches(emailPattern))
        {
            Friend friend = new Friend(idNum, emailString, firstNameString, surnameString);

            myDB.addNewFriend(friend);
    //            startActivity(new Intent(this, ViewAllFriends.class));

        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Email not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_home) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        }
        else if(id == R.id.action_search)
        {
//            startActivity(new Intent(this, SearchFriends.class));
            Toast.makeText(this, "Already on Add Friend Page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(id == R.id.action_view)
        {
//            startActivity(new Intent(this, ViewAllFriends.class));
            Toast.makeText(this, "Already on Add Friend Page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(id == R.id.action_add){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Already on# Add Friend Page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table create SQL does not have spaces between column names and column types for the last 3 columns.

Change

```
    String CREATE_FRIENDS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
        + ID_COL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + EMAIL + "TEXT,"
        + FIRST_NAME + "TEXT,"
        + SURNAME + "TEXT" + ")";
```

to :-

```
    String CREATE_FRIENDS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
        + ID_COL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + EMAIL + " TEXT,"
        + FIRST_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + SURNAME + " TEXT" + ")";
```

then do **one** of the following

- delete the App's data and rerun
- uninstall the App and rerun
- change `public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;` to `public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;` and rerun the App.

---

You may also wish to consider the following:

1) You can simplify looping through the cursor by using:-

```
    while(cursor.moveToNext) {
        ....
    }
```

2) You may reduce issues with determining/calculating column offsets by taking advantage of the Cursor's `getColumnIndex(columnname)` method rather than hard coding the offsets.

With both 1 and 2 you code could be:-

```
while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
    Friend friend = new Friend();
    friend.setFriendID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ID_COL))));
    friend.setEmailAddress(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EMAIL)));
    friend.setFirstName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FIRST_NAME)));
    friend.setSurname(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SURNAME)));

    //Adding to list
    friendList.add(friend);
}
```

Comment: Thats it! It was something I didn't look for but I will now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

this is a really easy error to fix,
you should basically read the error message, is part of your career
you have an inserting error because...

> table friends_table has no column named EMAIL (code 1):

So what do you think could be?
Of course you have to create a column EMAIL.
You will think of course that you created the email but **what you miss are the spaces.**  Basically when you create a Table you have to take care that the SQL query is perfectly formed.

so instead to write "TEXT" you should write " TEXT" leaving a space on both the fields EMAIL and SURNAME because they are wrong written in this way.

Also you should consider that if you run you app with an emulator or device that you have to `uninstall` your app before, so that when you will relaunch with Run will be installed from scratch a new "correct" database.